# Aggregate concept in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `mk`

```
    HomeID  tract     value
1        1 FIPS04 314522.70
2        2 FIPS03 201834.99
3        3 FIPS03 196524.75
4        4 FIPS03 198746.18
5        5 FIPS04 296456.83
6        6 FIPS02 130258.99
7        7 FIPS02 122678.42
8        8 FIPS02 152234.58
9        9 FIPS03 164635.87
10      10 FIPS02 131209.42
```

I have to aggregate the dataframe by `tract` and put those values into a new dataframe and calculate the aggregated  values of `mean`,`sd`,`length`.

Comment: Just do `aggregate(value~tra, mk, mean)`  For multiple functions `f1 <- function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x),length(x));do.call(data.frame, aggregate(value~tra, mk, f1))`

Comment: The factor given was tra... but not value..

Comment: If you are grouping by 'tra', that is the syntax or use `library(dplyr);mk %>% group_by(tra) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, n()), value)`  According to your post `I have to aggregate the dataframe by tra`

Comment: The first parameter.. is the factor by which we should aggregate right? So as per my question it should be value or tra?

Comment: It is grouping by 'tra' and getting the `mean`, `sd` etc of 'value'.  Does it makes sense to get the `mean` of 'tra'?

Comment: Ok, is it not required to have HomeID

Comment: I am not sure what you are after.  HomeID in your example seems to be unique for each element.

Comment: I want to know if all columns can be displayed or not

Comment: In that case you may need `mutate_each` instead of `summarise_each`.  I am not sure about your expected output